React component fetch server data once but render every time
I am new in react. I have a component WarehouseSelect that I use in different component in one data table product page. For example in Filter warehouse, Update Warehouse in products loop. Here is my component
export default function WarehouseSelect(
    {warehouse, setWarehouse}: { warehouse: number; setWarehouse: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>}
) {

    const [warehouses, setWarehouses] = useSessionStorage<Warehouse[]>('warehouses', []);

    useEffect(() => {
        
            if (warehouses?.length) return;

              axios.get("/api/warehouses")
                    .then((response) => setWarehouses(response.data.data))
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <Select
            isRequired
            label="Warehouse"
            placeholder="Select Warehouse"
            radius="none"
            value={warehouse}
            onChange={setWarehouse}
            items={warehouses ? warehouses : undefined}
        >
            {(wh) => <SelectItem key={wh.id}>{wh.name}</SelectItem> }
        </Select>
    );
}

My problem is when I render this component it fetch server data every time. I expect from this When the component will render then if warehouses not exist in session or state or localstorage then is fetch from server. How can I implement it?

How are you using WarehouseSelect? What are you passing to it? Can you provide an example

I suppose the core issue is that your set called way later than few render calls, creating duplicate requests until the state is set. You need additional state which would block creating another request if there is one in progress already (should be set on beginning of the useEffect)

Hi, Thank you for the post. Can you please include in your question the relevant codes on the following two calling sites of the component ? "...For example in Filter warehouse, Update Warehouse in products loop. Here is my component"

You need to amend useEffect in order to check if warehouse data is already stored in sessionStorage. If the data is available, load it from sessionStorage. If not fetch it from the server and store it in sessionStorage.
 useEffect(() => {
        // Check if data is already in sessionStorage
        const storedWarehouses = sessionStorage.getItem('warehouses')

        if (storedWarehouses) {
            // If data is in sessionStorage, set it to state
            setWarehouses(JSON.parse(storedWarehouses))
        } else {
            // If no data, fetch it from the server
            axios.get("/api/warehouses")
                .then((response) => {
                    const fetchedWarehouses = response.data.data;
                    setWarehouses(fetchedWarehouses)
                    // Save the fetched data in sessionStorage
                    sessionStorage.setItem('warehouses', JSON.stringify(fetchedWarehouses))
                })
        }
    }, [])

